# Detect Mouse leave stage while dragging in Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, mouseevent

[Event.MOUSE_LEAVE](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#event:mouseLeave) is great in Actionscript 3, but it doesn't seem to fire if the user is holding their left (or right for that matter) mouse button down.

Is there a way to detect if the mouse leaves the Flash movie while the mouse is held down? Or if it is released outside the flash movie?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get all of that requires a little bit of a hack.  You have to store whether the mouse is off the stage or not and handle the `Event.MOUSE_LEAVE` event accordingly. Doing it this way gives you all the normal mouse functionality including not stopping the drag just because the mouse went off stage. Since the user might come back on stage and continue the drag it waits 'til the user releases the mouse either on or off stage.

```
var mouseOffStage:Boolean;

var bonk:YourDisplayObject = new YourDisplayObject()
addChild(bonk);
bonk.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function():void {
  mouseOffStage = false;

  bonk.startDrag();

  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
  stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeave);
  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOut);
  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOver);
})

private function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent) :void {
  trace("Mouse Up On Stage")
  bonk.stopDrag()
}

private function mouseLeave(e:Event) :void {
  if(mouseOffStage){
    trace("mouse up and off stage");
    bonk.stopDrag();
  }else{
    trace("mouse has left the stage");
    //no reason to stop drag here as the user hasn't released the mouse yet
  }
}

private function mouseOut(e:MouseEvent) :void {
  mouseOffStage = true;
  trace("mouse has left the stage")
}

private function mouseOver(e:MouseEvent) :void {
  mouseOffStage = false;
  trace("mouse has come back on stage");
}
```

The hack is that the `MOUSE_LEAVE` event, not the `MOUSE_UP` event, gets fired when the mouse is released off stage so you have to keep track of whether or not the mouse was already off stage when it was released.

after the drag is finished you of course want to remove all the event listeners associated with detecting mouse-outs and mouse-ups but that code was left out for readability.

Comment: Words cannot really express how long i've been f**king this up and how glad i am i stumbled on this answer.

Comment: In Flash 15 (or earlier), mouse-up out-of-stage doesn't produce mouse-leave (as greggreg suggests) but mouse-up. Sandra Bollocks.

Just check the mouse (stage) co-ordinates in mouseMove and compare against stage dimensions to realize if in-or-out of stage..!

Answer (score 4):

here's what I do:

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);

private function onMouseDown(_e:MouseEvent):void
{
    mc2.startDrag(params);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, onMouseLeave);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
}

private function onMouseUp(_e:MouseEvent):void
{
    ms2.stopDrag();
}

private function onMouseLeave(_e:Event):void
{
    mc2.stopDrag();
}

private function onMouseOut(_e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (e.stageX <= 0 || e.stageX >= stage.stageWidth || e.stageY <= 0 || e.stageY >= stage.stageHeight)
    {
        mc2.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple tricky traps not to fall into  :

One bizarre thing is that in Chrome + Firefox, the MOUSE_LEAVE event isn't dispatched for a [WMODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embed/6050201#6050201) of `OPAQUE` or`TRANSPARENT`. It just doesn't fire - mouse down or up.

With `WINDOW` it works fine. That one took me a long time to find out! grr... http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-892

---

Second, make sure you're using `Event` for the parameter type for your `Event.MOUSE_LEAVE` handler and not `MouseEvent`. If you try to handle `MOUSE_LEAVE` with `e:MouseEvent` you'll get an error that you may never see (unless you're using the debug flash player). It's a very easy mistake to make because you're probably pointing all your other handlers to the same method.

Here's what I do: (just call my main `endDrag` from `mouseLeave(e:Event)`

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drag);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endDrag);
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, endDrag);
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeave);

private function mouseLeave(e:Event):void
{
    endDrag(new MouseEvent("MOUSE_LEAVE"));
}

public function endDrag(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    /// handle end drag
}
```

Comment: .. line " stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, endDrag);" , what kind of event is that?

Comment: It's funny, you said beware of MOUSE_LEAVE being passed as a MouseEvent parameter, yet you made the same mistake with Event.DEACTIVATE -> endDrag. :-)

Comment: Oops. I got away for it for almost four years :)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem in a PDF type viewer I had to build into a Flex application.  I wanted the pan functions to still work even if the mouse left the stage or the browser window.  Here is how I accomplished this, I've changed the code to remove references to Flex Framework classes so this should be applicable to any AS3 project.  On `mouseDown` I would start tracking these values on a timer.  `_client` can be any `flash.display.DisplayObject` in the target stage.  In my case it was a Flex `mx.controls.SWFLoader` object, but in your case I suppose it would be the drag target:

```
private function get currentMouseX():Number
{
     return _client.stage.mouseX; 
}

private function get currentMouseY():Number
{
     return _client.stage.mouseY; 
}
```

The `stage.mouseX` and `stage.mouseY` values are defined relative to the stage whether the mouse is in the stage or even in the browser window (at least in Flash Player 10, I haven't tested this in earlier flash player versions).  To see if the mouse is outside the stage just test and see if these values are within the stage, like so:

```
if (currentMouseY < 0 || 
    currentMouseY > _client.stage.height || 
    currentMouseX < 0 || 
    currentMouseX > _client.stage.width)
{
     // Do something here
}
```

EDIT: As to detecting a `mouseUp` event outside of the stage, if you register a listener on the stage, a mouseUp will be issued even if the event occurs outside of the stage or the browser.  Here is the code for how I handle events function for reference.  The `_client` object can be any `flash.display.DisplayObject`:

```
 // attach the events like so when you initialize
 _client.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN  , handleMouse);   
 _client.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT   , handleMouse);
 _client.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER  , handleMouse);
//

// and handle them like this:
 private function handleMouse(e:MouseEvent):void
 {
      switch(e.type)
      {

          case "mouseDown":

         // add listeners, notice the mouse move and mouse up are 
         // attached to the stage, not the display object this way
         // events are issued regardless of whether the mouse is in 
         // the stage or even within the browser window

         _client.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouse);
         _client.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMouse);      
         _client.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouse);    


         // remove listeners     
         _client.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouse); 

         //
         // commands / actions 

         break;


         case "mouseUp":

         // add listeners
        _client.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouse); 


         // remove listeners 
         _client.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouse);
         _client.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouse);    


         // commands/actions 

         break;


         case "click":


         // add listeners
         _client.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, handleMouse);


         // remove listeners    
         _client.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMouse); 


         // commands / actions

         break;

         case "mouseMove":

         // add listeners


         // remove listeners
         _client.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouse);
         _client.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMouse);   


         // commands 

         break;

         case "mouseOut":

         // add listeners


         // remove listeners

         // commands / actions

         break;

         case "mouseOver":

         // add listeners


         // remove listeners


         // commands /actions

         break;
     }
 }
```

EDIT: Removed references to Flex framework classes
EDIT: I remember that there may be some problem with events outside of the browser window when the application is run in the Safari browser on Mac OSX.  Make sure you test this code in that browser if you use it.  This wasn't a problem in my application, so I didn't look into the issue further.

Comment: I made some edits to include additional code and explanation, as well as remove references to Flex Framework classes.  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing something where you are dragging a MovieClip this seems to work nicely.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
```

EDIT - never mind

Comment: That would work, if what you are dragging was always under the mouse. But in my case, it's for a horizontal scrollbar. The problem is that if you drag the scrollbar, and move the mouse up or down (off the bar) then it will fire the event.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean :S

Comment: Perhaps if all else fails you could always do something where on ENTER_FRAME you check the mouse coordinates and see if they are outside of the stage?

Comment: Checking to see if the mouse coordinates are out side the stage wont work, because flash stops updating the coordinates when the mouse leaves the stage. So they can never be "outside the stage".

Comment: Attaching a mouseUp instead of a mouseOut listener to the stage will work.  See my answer for code.

Comment: MOUSE_OUT did work, the only problem was if there was say a component on stage moving out of the object would trigger the event. By checking the co-ordinates on the event handler it could be determined if it was actually out of the stage which is what Michal M's solution does. He just beat me to it after I relooked at the problem :P

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to detect if the mouse leaves the Flash movie while the mouse is held down?

Not that i know of

> Or if it is released outside the flash movie?

Event.MOUSE_LEAVE does happen when you release outside.

more info here
http://blog.zupko.info/?p=3
see JIMISAACS comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var youMax_X:Number; //set this var to Max x
    var youMax_Y:Number; //set this var to `enter code here`Max y

    var dragBounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,youMax_X,yourMax_Y);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,handleDown);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,handleUp);


    private function handleDown(e:Event):void{
            this.startDrag(false,dragBounds);
    }
    private function handleUp(e:Event):void{
        this.stopDrag();
    }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Please try to avoid posting code-only answers. Explain what your code does and how. Describe how it solves the problem posed in the question you're answering.

Comment: It's self-explanatory for god's shake

Comment: That's even better than my solution, but mine has the advantage that it can be used with any display object (i.e. Bitmaps too), where as 'startDrag' is a Sprite-only function

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right answer. Custom class you pass a DisplayObject to and will drag it till mouse-up or mouse out-of-stage. Customize at will:

```
package fanlib.gfx
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;

    public class Drag
    {
        private var obj:DisplayObject;
        private var point:Point = new Point();
        private var stg:Stage;

        public function Drag(obj:DisplayObject)
        {
            this.obj = obj;
            stg = Stg.Get();
            stg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
            stg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrag);
            //stg.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, stopDrag); // sh*t just won't fire
            point.setTo(stg.mouseX, stg.mouseY);
        }

        private function mouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
            if (stg.mouseX <= 0 ||
                stg.mouseY <= 0 ||
                stg.mouseX >= stg.stageWidth ||
                stg.mouseY >= stg.stageHeight) {
                stopDrag();
                return;
            }
            obj.x += stg.mouseX - point.x;
            obj.y += stg.mouseY - point.y;
            point.setTo(stg.mouseX, stg.mouseY);
        }

        public function stopDrag(e:* = null):void {
            stg.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
            stg.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrag);
            //stg.removeEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, stopDrag);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can mouse x/y ever be less than 0 and greater than the stage width/height?

Comment: Yup, if having the mouse button pressed