# How to handle both CLICK and MouseDown events in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mouseevent, onmousedown

I have a scenario where I am listening to both `CLICK` and `MouseDown` events for an object.

On MouseDown I do a `startDrag()`. And on Click, I perform something else.

But the problem is that, MouseDown event fires first and it initiates a drag. The click event does not fire. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen MouseDown event and when it fires subscribe MouseMove and MouseUp events and remember coordinates of cursor on MouseDown. Then determine a delta (say 1px) which will be a sign of starting dragging. So if MouseMove invokes you check current mouse position and determine if user is really dragging (using your delta). In this case invoke `startDrag()`. In other case Click event will be invoked.

And remember unsubscribing events! :)

Comment: This is the way to do it.  I posted some code you might find useful in an answer to another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563434/detect-mouse-leave-stage-while-dragging-in-actionscript-3/1691635#1691635