# Javascript pop-up over Vimeo video - CSS layout order

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there such thing as a layer or an order of items that conflict in the same space? 
I have a pop-up signin box, somewhat similar to Twitter.com, but when it pops open, it is behind a Vimeo video in the middle of the screen.  Is there a CSS style to make it appear on top of the video instead of behind it?  In graphic design tools there is often a move-to-front option, any equivalent to that in CSS?  Can't show my page yet or I would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the `z-index` in css. The higher is more to the front.

However... you are probably dealing with flash transparency here instead. To fix that you will have to set the `wmode` to `transparent`. See this question for more info about `wmode`: [differences between using wmode="transparent", "opaque", or "window" for an embedded object on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmodetransparent-opaque-window-for-an-embedded)