# iPad Safari mobile seems to ignore z-indexing position for html5 video elements

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, html5-video

I got a video element on a page that's working fine both in safari mobile and desktop.
I have a seme-transparent pull-down menu that's working fine. The problem is, when the menu is over the video element, on the desktop safari i can see the video under the menu (as desired), while on the mobile version the video element stay on the foreground (ugly) no matter what i tell the css. Is there any workaround?

[image: An image of the problem]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The issue only occurs if the video element was dynamically created. If the element was just in the page as it loaded, `z-index` works fine.

You can fix z-index on dynamically created videos by giving the video element `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d`.

Yep, it's as bad as haslayout on IE!

Comment: I'm not getting this to work; can you please post an example?

Comment: +1 you are right! this happens only on dynamically created elements. Thank you so so much:)

Comment: You also have to have the HTML property "controls" not present. See this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261079/mobile-safari-link-a-element-over-video-element-does-not-work-on-click).

Comment: My video is not dynamically created and still ignores it's z-index. Adding the `transform-style` CSS property also does not help.

Comment: Can confirm that it also happens with a "static" video tag, no controls. As soon as I unmute my custom controls and anything else go behind the video. `-webkit-transform-style` does help though!

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately not.

Based on my experience and understanding of how iOS currently works, this isn't possible.

Mobile Safari on the iPad cuts a hole for a Quicktime window , which plays back the video using the built in hardware acceleration to improve battery life. (The iPhone and iPod Touch just open it up in a separate window to achieve the same effect.)

This window doesn't play nicely with the other HTML on the page. In fact, I haven't found a way to get mobile Safari to display anything on top of a  tag. My guess is that this is because the hardware acceleration only allows for video scaling and positioning, and that it's only able to handle one video at a time.

Comment: Now that's sad. I will have to stop and hide the video when the menu is opened. It's an ugly workaround, let's hope someone come up with a solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It can be done. as Jaffa The Cake said, this thing happens only on dynamically inserted video elements

Answer (score 9):

I'm using flowplayer and a simple CSS dropdown menu and had the same problem.

I have drop down menu that, when tapped, covers part of the video area.  The submenu shows up over the video as expected, but no touch events were being sent.

I fixed it by combining a couple of suggestions from others answering this question: I set **visibility:*hidden*** when opening the menu and **visibility:*visible*** when closing the submenu, AND set the **-webkit-transform-style:*preserve-3d*** CSS property on the video.

Here's the pertinent code.  I left out the CSS for the menubar, but it does what you might expect - resulting in a menu that covers portions of the video.

**menu and video HTML**

```
<div id='nav'>
  <ul>
    ... <!-- bunch of ul/li stuff here for the menu and submenus -->
  </ul>
</div>
<div id='videoplayer'><!-- for flowplayer --></div>
```

**CSS**

```
video {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav li").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).fadeIn(300);
      $("video").css({visibility:"hidden"});
    },
    function(){ 
      $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
      $("video").css({visibility:"visible"});
    }
  );
);
```

Comment: TROY YOU ARE A LIFESAVER! Troy's answer is the answer if you're having this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951463/html5-video-layering-on-ipad

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using MediaElement js and experience the same problem. After switching the visibility of the video between 'visible' and 'hidden' by js, my problem of disordered display is gone (for my case) :)

Answer (score 9):

When you have an element you want to be in front of your `<video>` in Safari, you need to set into that element the `transform: translateZ(1px)` or more pixels, as Safari is setting to your `<video>` element a 0 value for Z axis (`transform: translateZ(0)`).

This is the only thing it worked to me. No `z-index`, no `transform-style:preserve-3d`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer really saves my day. 
I'm using Safari mobile on iOS14. In my case, I have a slick with video as a background and some div's overlayed on it. It's perfectly overlayed when it is still, but the video will overlay those div's when I swipe the slick. I add `-webkit-transform: translateZ(1px)` to those div's and now it's perfect.

Comment: I also “lost” 8h trying to find the fix  

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to place a menu div over a html5 video tag in mobile-safari on the ipad. To be honest I didn't have any problems and it just worked. It could be though because I was using CSS3 animations and therefore the GPU? You could try using a hack to add an element to the GPU. If you put `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` on the element it should force it to use the GPU...

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d`

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d` and `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0)` didn't work for me.

Using Flowplayer with the ipad plugin and the controlbar plugin allowed me to remove the ipad created control bar and replace it with something that can be z-indexed below my modal windows.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this also. The only thing that I could get to work for me was to add

```
display:none
```

to the video tag when showing a div over it that needed to be clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix `z-index` on dynamically created videos by giving the video element `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d`.

This worked for me with a dynamically created video element. I also set the `z-index` of the over-laying div to `z-index: 888;` which may also have helped.

Comment: You also have to have the HTML property "controls" not present. See this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261079/mobile-safari-link-a-element-over-video-element-does-not-work-on-click).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem which was occurring on mobile devices with an off canvas menu. When the menu was over the video you could not tap any of the menu items.

I fixed it my moving the video somewhere else when the menu was on by positioning it absolutely at -100000px when the menu was not displayed it set it back being positioned relatively.

I found using display none did not work as when you set it to block again the video would not work.

I also tried setting the height to 0 - this did not work as the video still seemed to take up the space even though you couldn't see it.

The final method seems a bit extreme but it is not really noticeable when it is being used.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that will work on both the iPad and iPhone. I tried removing the controls and then add them again, but this worked only on iPad not on iPhone. After remove the opacity and then add it again it worked on iPhone also.

```
$("#overlay_open").click(function(){
  $("video").prop("controls", false);
  $("video").css("opacity", 0);
});

$("#overlay_close").click(function(){
  $("video").prop("controls", true);
  $("video").css("opacity", 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue today & had to cobble together a solution from multiple answers since none fully handled the problem ...

I have video elements in a collapsed "table view" style list that were capturing touch events on iPhone when trying to tap on other list items. On iPhone the videos would play when tapping other collapsed elements that happened to be occupying the same spot on screen.

Fixing this required all of the following:

1) Using this:

```
video{
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
```

... didn't seem to have any effect, but I left it in anyway. Everything's working now so I don't want to screw with it further :)

2) Toggling  `visibility: hidden` alone didn't work, and `display:none` didn't work as expected.

3) In addition to "visibility" the HTML5 video tag `controls` attribute also has to be added/removed dynamically. Either:

`$("video").css({visibility:"hidden"}).removeAttr("controls");` or `$("video").css({visibility:"visible"}).attr("controls", "controls");`

4) Must set visibility/controls on document load based on initial browser/screen size

5) Although the main concern was the screwy iPhone behavior, I also had to account for responsive window size changes above my smallest media query breakpoint of 600px - otherwise the videos would appear/disappear at the wrong screen sizes.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 600){
        $("video").css({visibility:"visible"}).attr("controls", "controls");
    }
});
```

Quite a pain to work around what's essentially a stupid mobile Safari bug... I sure hope it works on iPad when I test it later...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into issues with this still, another fix that ended up working for me was to change the options in the embed code to not allow controls, suggested videos, and video title and player options.  I added a simple [Modernizr.MQ](http://modernizr.com/docs/) query to change the src for tablet and mobile, and included the following to the iframe src for mobile:

?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0

I never completely tracked down why this works, but my guess is that the controls have some user-agent style that gives them a high z-index and makes the element sit on top of everything.