# HTML5 video: possible to place regular html content over video

Tags: html, html5-video

Just wondering if anyone knows any tricks to getting regular html content (mainly an img tag) to display on top of a video (via the video tag)?

Answer (score 6):

As others have intimated it's very easy to position HTML elements on top of `VIDEO` elements using absolute positioning. The challenge comes when you try to capture events on them in the iPhone, iPod and possibly older Android phones that don't play video assets inline on the page (as opposed to in a thin native playback client) since in those instances the `VIDEO` element greedily captures events.

If you use an `IMAGE` element or a `DIV` with its `background-image` set to an image you want to use as a "poster" or "thumbnail" then your users won't be able to tap on them to get the video to start playing -- the mobile browser will treat this behavior as if nothing but the `VIDEO` element exists in that space (good if you happen to click in the middle where the "big play" button is but not so helpful if you, say, have a custom control not in the middle.

The solution I've used in the past is to just put the `IMG` or `DIV` poster on the page where you would normally put the `VIDEO` element and shift the `VIDEO` element offscreen (absolutely positioned with `left` style set to, say, -3000px) so it can no longer hoard those events.

I know this isn't exactly what was asked, but hopefully this information will prove useful to someone.

Comment: +1 I agree with your method. I had to implement a third party library that required a user action i.e. clicking a button. Quicktime player was a nightmare. I initially set the video element to display:none and only showed it after the users action.

You method is perfect as it really doesn't matter where the video element lives as after all its just going to open in full screen anywhere. 

A little bit off css can fool the users

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683211/ipad-safari-mobile-seems-to-ignore-z-indexing-position-for-html5-video-elements

Answer (score 4):

You can simply put html elements on top of HTML5 video by positioning them absolutly on top of the video. Give both the video element and the HTML element a "position:absolute" and put the HTML element a z-index higher than the video element's.

Comment: Here's a example. But you should try to do it yourself next time. Costs me 5 min ;): http://jsfiddle.net/GxvyG/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the poster attribute? That way you can display an image until the video is loaded or play.

Comment: the idea is i am trying to integrate the video into part of the design of the site, where an area along the top of the video overlaps to make the video appear as though it is partly underneath. i tried to put the image inside the video itself, but due to the compression, the colors and size change slightly and the difference is quite noticeable.

Comment: The only solution I can think of for this particular example is to automatically put the div/img on top of the video with JavaScript. That way the video will be loaded along with the page and won't interfere with the image. You might want to keep an eye on the z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the video as background for that div? Not sure if it would work for your layout, but it seems logical...

Comment: how do you set a video as a background?

Comment: It has to do with using the <canvas> and <video elements together. I'm mot an HTML5 guru. I saw the basics on this site: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/     He's using the canvas to draw the video in the background, and then lays a video tag over it. I think you should be able to place a canvas for the BG video, and use a poster image on the video element, or lay an image over the canvas instead of the video.  I'm told that the video element can be used as a bg element like you would an image, but I can't find an example of that anywhere, so maybe I spoke too soon. Hope that helps.