# iframe youtube always on top of other elements on mobile

Tags: html, flash, youtube, html5-video

I am using youtubes  to embed my vidoes and have some elements that should appear on top o the video if clicked on.

This works perfectly on desktop browsers just not on mobiles themselves.

I have tried `?wmode=transparent` to no avail.

Does anybody have any other tricks i can try?

Comment: could you make a codepen with your problem? I suspect z-indexes is the answer, but I will have to do some testing.

Comment: yup, tried z-index naturally. This with absolutes

Comment: set a parent div in place for the video and apply a position and z-index value for that parent div.  See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

See: [HTML5 video: possible to place regular html content over video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626700/html5-video-possible-to-place-regular-html-content-over-video)

Your issue may be similar i.e. quicktime player(ios) hijacking that area of the browser. The above link has a few hacks.