# Close button over HTML5 video (iPad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, html

I have to embed a video on a web page with a button to close and stop the video.
Once closed an image will be displayed below.

Everything is working fine on all browsers.

The problem is on the iPad...

Basically on the iPad the "close" button doesn't work (not clickable). Moving it on the side of the video it works (close the video) but it doesn't pause it. The video is hosted on Wistia. It plays without problems...

"Every single Wistia embed code type automatically supports HTML5 when it detects a device that requires it (ie. iPhones, iPads)."

Here is the URL:

http://www.bbyd.eu/projects/test/video_ecom/index.html

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us exactly what the problem on the iPad is.

Comment: Its a flash video no ? I think ipads have problems with that.

Comment: its not a flash video. its mp4

Comment: Ipads will not read flash videos, because there is no flash on ipads.

Comment: Basically on the iPad the "close" button doesn't work (not clickable). Moving it on the side of the video it works (close the video) but it doesn't pause it. The video is hosted on Wistia. It plays without problems... 
Thanks!

Comment: "Every single Wistia embed code type automatically supports HTML5 when it detects a device that requires it (ie. iPhones, iPads)."

Comment: It places some kind of overlay over the top of the player. Only affects iPad it seems. Adjusting z-index doesnt seem to help either. You'll need to come up with some kind of other work around for iPads.

Comment: have a look at this SO question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261079/mobile-safari-link-a-element-over-video-element-does-not-work-on-click

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a click/touchstart listener to the video element and then close and pause it if the interaction is in that area.

Comment: Before anyone says something about "this should be a comment", I would if stack exchange's rules would let me.