# AS3 MOUSE_LEAVE problem

Tags: actionscript-3

I am coding a drag and drop application where I can grab an object and then place it over different object containers. When I am dragging the object (keeping the mouse button pressed) and I leave the stage, I can still control the object with the mouse...this is not what I want.

I would like to lose control of the object when the mouse leaves the stage.

I tried to remove the event listener for MOUSE_DOWN on a MOUSE_LEAVE event but nothing.

I also tried to dispatch a MOUSE_UP event on a MOUSE_LEAVE event but it does not work either...it works only if I manually release the mouse button.

Is there any way to override the MOUSE_DOWN event when the user moves the mouse away from the screen but he is still pressing the mouse button??? 
Any suggestion???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the stage actually listening to the MOUSE_LEAVE event? In any case , check this article, it may help:
http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/detecting_when_mouse_leaves_movie.htm

Comment: but it is not triggered when I keep pressing the mouse button down.

Comment: you're right , same thing in the example i've given you. have you tried loxxy's solutions? this should definitely work, dispatch a MouseUp event  or get the stage to dispatch a MouseLeave event when the mouse is out of bounds

Comment: it works as long as I release the mouse button when I am moving the mouse out of bounds. I set x an y limits therefore my object is stuck by the bounds if I leave the stage  but I keep pressing down the mouse button.(it does not disappear like the example)...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple tricky traps not to fall into  :

One bizarre thing is that in Chrome + Firefox, the MOUSE_LEAVE event isn't dispatched for a [WMODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embed/6050201#6050201) of `OPAQUE` or`TRANSPARENT`. It just doesn't fire - mouse down or up.

With `WINDOW` it works fine. That one took me a long time to find out! grr... http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-892

---

Second, make sure you're using `Event` for the parameter type for your `Event.MOUSE_LEAVE` handler and not `MouseEvent`. If you try to handle `MOUSE_LEAVE` with `e:MouseEvent` you'll get an error that you may never see (unless you're using the debug flash player). It's a very easy mistake to make because you're probably pointing all your other handlers to the same method.

Here's what I do: (just call my main `endDrag` from `mouseLeave(e:Event)`

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drag);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endDrag);
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, endDrag);
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeave);

private function mouseLeave(e:Event):void
{
    endDrag(new MouseEvent("MOUSE_LEAVE"));
}

public function endDrag(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    /// handle end drag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about the user leaving the flash content altogether with mouse clicked, and when he/she returns it continues the process right?

I suggest, you track the mouse x & y coordinates. Set a condition which triggers the mouse up event handler when the x or y is equal to the stage width or height respectively.

Comment: I tried to do something like that but the MOUSE_UP event is not triggered if I keep pressing the mouse button down...I guess it is triggered for an instant and then the MOUSE_DOWN event is triggered again...

Answer (score 0):

When you drag an object outside the flash movie, the object will fire a MOUSE_OUT event. You can listen to this event, use a variable to check if the object is being dragged, and, if so, dispatch a MOUSE_UP event.

```
some_object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
some_object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
some_object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutHandler);

private function mouseOutHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (isDragging)
        e.target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
}

private function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{   
    e.target.startDrag();
    isDragging = true;
}

private function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{   
    e.target.stopDrag();
    isDragging = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I dropped Flash development for Android quite a while ago ;)