# Dropdown menus are "stopping" my Flash animation, causing choppy animation. IE ONLY

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

**Background:**

On a recent website, I'm using a jQuery driven dropdown menu in addition to a Flash scrolling animation.

**Note:** I am only using the Flash animation in IE only as I created an equivalent, jQuery based animation for all other browsers (because, surprise, IE didn't handle the jQuery version). So please look at this in IE only.

http://www.surveyinitiative.co.uk/

**The Problem**

When you hover over the dropdown menus, the Flash animation temporarily "freezes" and the continues. This causes choppy behavior in the Flash animation.

**Questions**

1. Whey is this happening?
2. Is there anything I can do to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `wmode="opaque"` parameter to your movie object.

See: [differences between using wmode="transparent", "opaque", or "window" for an embedded object on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmodetransparent-opaque-window-for-an-embedded)

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem. It's almost as if the Flash and the javascript are running on the same thread.

Comment: Taking a closer look, it seems your extensive use of CANVAS is competing for too many CPU cycles. You're paying the price for non-standard fonts.