# Flash always above? Fix with css?

Tags: html, css, flash

So i recently added a video from youtube on my website and my footer is positioned as fixed, and the flash move goes above it, is it any way to fix that? Tricks and mix with css maybe?

Any help would be greatly thanked..

Preview: http://swipper.org

-swipper

Answer (score 3):

In your YouTube iframe, add `&amp;wmode=Opaque` to the URL, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue)

Note that transparent wmode usually isn't necessary (vs "opaque") for positioning, unless you truly want to make part of the Flash transparent since it's more resource intensive.

Comment: +1. Transparent `wmode` only when the flash contains transparent elements.

Answer (score 2):

Set the background of your Flash file to transparent by setting the `wmode` parameter to `transparent` in the embed code. See [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use your URL like "http://www.youtube.com/embed/OleH02U_qRw?wmode=opaque", means you have to add "?wmode=opaque" at the end of URL then it will work fine for all major browsers.