# wmode parameter for YouTube iframe embed

Tags: flash, iframe, youtube, wmode

Setting a `wmode` parameter when embedding via the YouTube iframe (see [Youtube iframe wmode issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue)) appears to no-longer work, at least in Chrome 14 and reportedly IE as well.  I've created this jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/HYPBb/1/.  Note how the `div` does not overlap the Flash within the iframe.

Is this a known issue?  There doesn't seem to be a developer forum on YouTube's site to report this.  Is there now an alternative way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that in moving over to the new `iframe` embedding, I didn't properly convert the URL.  If the Flash URL looks like this:

> http://www.youtube.com/v/FOHJUrcVdJk

The iframe URL should look like this:

> http://www.youtube.com/embed/FOHJUrcVdJk

[The updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYPBb/3/) shows that the `wmode` query string parameter now works after converting the URL.