# YouTube video overlaps on the HTML drop down menu (Superfish)

Tags: html, youtube, flash

I have a webpage, having drop down menus using Superfish. I have embedded a YouTube video on that page, using iframe. The problem is, YouTube video overlaps the menu. This issue is there on IE and Chrome. On Firefox, this works fine.

The solution to this issue is to have `<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />` within the `<object>` tag. But as this is an YouTube video, and we are using iframe to embed the YouTube video, we can't add `<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />` to the code.

There is another solution and which works right now is, to embed the YouTube video using the old code.

I would like to know how to fix this issue?

Comment: This answer should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue/4211320#4211320

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `?wmode=transparent` at the end of your url