# z-index is not working with fancybox in google chrome

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I am using a lightbox created by FancyBox. It opens a youtube video and it works fine. In google chrome, I did notice that the close button is going behind the video. I messed with the z-index and its not working properly in google chrome. I messed with it in firefox and it works just fine. The positions are set and everything. Any ideas?

Here is the website: http://theadamgrp.com/test/hcsmu/
Click on the "Click here to watch his testimonial" next to a thumbnail picture on your right.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you using the [latest version of fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)?

Comment: I can't repro the problem in Chrome 18 (OS X). http://i.stack.imgur.com/gNetf.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube iframe wmode issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue)

Comment: yes i am using the latest version. The &wmode=transparent worked nicely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the problem as described in chromium 17 / ubuntu.

Adding the following to the YouTube iframe's URL fixes it for me:

```
&wmode=transparent
```

YouTube passes the `wmode` URL parameter into the SWF object. Adobe has [more information](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_) on Flash's `wmode` property.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using position:relative/abosulte/etc... for the positioned DIV, or the z-index will not matter.