# video not working in bootstrap modal pop up on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to play video in Modal Pop up, it works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.

## Below is the Code:

```
<a href="#video" data-toggle="modal" id="clickForVideo">
  Click Me
</a>
```

==========

Modal poop up code:

==========

```
<div class="modal fade" id="video" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body modal-video">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" ></iframe>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

==========

JS code:

==========

```
$(document).on("click", '#clickForVideo', function() {
  var src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/itTskyFLSS8?feature=player_embedded&autoplay=1';
  $('#video').modal('show');
  $('#video iframe').attr('src', src);
  $(".modal-video").fitVids();
});
```

==========

Comment: works for me, what version of FF are you using?  http://jsfiddle.net/GxmLg/

Comment: I am using Firefox 26.0 and OS: Ubuntu

Comment: Write something in console and check by click, the function call inside or not.

Comment: have tried it from console as well and function calls.

One thing I notice that Video is not working, Audio is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video not working in Modal popup due to Firefox plugin **Shockwave Flash**.

When I inactive the plugin everything works fine.

Below are the links for more description to the answer:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-common-audio-and-video-issues

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-issues-with-plugins-fix-problems

Comment: Hi ankush, my name is nikhil and I am also facing the same. issue. I just want your help to know where I may be wrong. So Can you please give me any contact details of yours.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, Sorry I missed your comment. My email address is jainankush12@gmail.com

Answer (score 5):

Adding this css code block in the page you have that modal will sort this issue.

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog{transform:none !important;}
```

Comment: I am trying to display webcam area on model dialog using https://pixlcore.com/demos/webcamjs/demos/basic.html. I have already try with by adding .modal.fade .modal-dialog{transform:none !important;} on my page but still not able to show webcam area.

Comment: I've been searching for an hour and this was the solution! I have an <object> tag that was not displaying the Windows Media Player and adding this style directly to the .modal-content DIV tag solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue, and managed to fix it by setting `wmode = transparent`
.

[See this answer for more.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211320/1101413)