# Overlaying a Fixed Header Over Elements When Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed header, so that when I scroll it remains at the top of the page so that visitors may navigate quickly or skip sections of the page.

Here is a picture of my problem:

[image]

The problem is pretty simple - I want my header to float over the top of any other objects instead of being hidden by them, but I assume there isn't a way to do it without javascript. Here is my CSS:

```
#primary header {
position: fixed;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
}
nav { /* positions nav menu */
position: fixed; /* keeps the nav bar fixed at top when scrolling */
top: 1.25%;
left: 27%;

}
nav a {
margin: 0 50px;
padding: 10px 20px;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Anyway I can do this? I am not familiar with Javascript, but would love some help!

Comment: Looks like you just need to use the [css z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the css `z-index` property on your fixed element. The higher the value, most in front it will get...

Like:

```
#primary header   {
    z-index: 999; /* SET THE NEEDED AMOUNT */
}
```

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks for your quick response!!! I would vote up, but I can't yet! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The z-index property is a common solution to elements which are positioned, but it looks like YouTube has provided a solution as well.

> Add a parameter to force YouTube iframe to set a low z-index.
>
> If you have any element you’ll like to show above a YouTube iframe you just have to add a parameter to the iFrame URL.
>
> [Ricard Torres' Personal Blog](http://php.quicoto.com/how-to-fix-z-index-in-youtube-iframes/)

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0HxNtWEIKhQ?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JSFiddle didn't seem to reproduce the issue, but here is an example as well:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9F5VT/)

[StackOverflow Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue)

[YouTube API Documentation (Preferable Embedding Method)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: If I misinterpreted your question, I do apologize. If you need to control all page elements then, LcSalazar's post is the most accurate.

Here is the JSFiddle example for that: http://jsfiddle.net/uLKhJ/