# How to active wmode transparent in video player

Tags: php, swfobject, video-player

I am trying to activate wmode in my video script.
I am not getting how to make it.

Below is my code.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setFlashPlayerSwf("demo_controller.swf");
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setMediaSrc("demo.mp4");
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setXMPSrc("demo_config.xml");

    TSC.playerConfiguration.setAutoHideControls(true);
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setBackgroundColor("#000000");
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setCaptionsEnabled(false);
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setSidebarEnabled(false);

    TSC.playerConfiguration.setAutoPlayMedia(false);
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setPosterImageSrc("demo_First_Frame.png");
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setIsSearchable(true);
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setEndActionType("stop");
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setEndActionParam("true");
    TSC.playerConfiguration.setAllowRewind(-1);

    TSC.localizationStrings.setLanguage(TSC.languageCodes.ENGLISH);
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        TSC.mediaPlayer.init("#tscVideoContent");
    });
</script>
```

I have tried this one TSC.playerConfiguration.setEndActionParam("wmode":"transparent");

Its not working.
 Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue

Comment: ok  sure  @ Anant..

Comment: @Anant Thank you for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution just doing bit changes in player-min.js:-

```html
co.wmode = "direct";


Just go to player-min.js and replace "direct" with "transparent"

It will work .


 co.wmode = "transparent";
```

Thank you.