# Flash: <param name="wmode" value="obaque">... obaque?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, embed, wmode

I've upgraded to FireFox 4 recently and suddenly one of my flash modules stopped working. This a copy/paste of the object structure from firebug (double dots are there for simplicity):

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data=".."  name="..">
    <param name="flashvars" value="..">
    <param name="wmode" value="obaque">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
</object>
```

Now... what's that ***obaque*** value on wmode param?.. It was meant to be "transparent"  actually, at least that's what I had in my embed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is the bug caused by [FlashFireBug](http://www.o-minds.com/products/flashfirebug).

> **in Apr 18, 2011 by Ashraf Amayreh**
>   Fixed the obaque problem, waiting or
>   Mozilla's approval.
>
> **in Apr 14, 2011 by Guest** I discovered
>   a problem with the param
>   wmode=transparent for a flash object
>   on Ubuntu 10.10, FF 3.6.16. Window
>   mode is reset to "**Obaque**" (which
>   should be "opaque" I think) with
>   activated FlashFirebug. Thank you so
>   much!

Answer (score 1):

It should be opaque

[differences between using wmode="transparent", "opaque", or "window" for an embedded object on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-window-for-an-embedded)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it was meant to be opaque not obaque?

See [differences between using wmode="transparent", "opaque", or "window" for an embedded object on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-window-for-an-embedded)

Answer (score 0):

Also use Embed tag in Object tag AS

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data=".."  name=".."> 
    <param name="flashvars" value="..">
    <param name="wmode" value="obaque">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <embed 
    src='*.swf' 
    pluginspage='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer' 
    flashVars='..'
    width='100%' height='600'
    /> 
    </object>
```

Hopes that helps