# Flowplayer playing over everything

Tags: css, video, z-index, flowplayer, jquery-dialog

I have a `flowplayer` that I am using with a few pictures below it. When you click on these pictures a `dialog` is created with an enlarged version of these pictures. The problem is the `flowplayer` will always be on top of the `dialog`.

I have tried setting the `z-index` of the `dialog` high and the `flowplayer` low, but it doesn't work.

Is there a method in `flowplayer` that will lower its `z-index` or allow for my `dialog` to be placed over it?

**Edit** Heres the flowplayer:

```
//Uses flowplayer to create player
$f('#rightVideoContent', "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
    //Creates a single clip for the flow player
    clip: {
        url: videoLocation,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoBuffering: true
    },
    plugins: {
        controls: null
    },
    onLoad: function () {
        //Do nothing here
    }
});
```

And here is the `div`

```
<div id = "rightVideoContent" class = "VideoDiv"></div>
```

I use `flowplayer-3.2.6.js` as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you've missed is :

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

[a bit more about wmode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embed)

**edit:** take a look at your code ... to embed a swf file you gotta have something like:

```
<object width="550" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf" />
    <embed src="somefilename.swf" width="550" height="400"></embed>
</object>
```

all you need to do is just add another `<param ...` after the first one

**edit2:** you should replace the second parameter ... instead of the url string put there

```
{src: 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf', wmode: 'transparent'}
```

Comment: Would I put this in the head or in the `div` that makes the flowplayer? Do you have an example of it?

Comment: @SsRide360: You put some code that applies `wmode` with a value of `transparent` (or `opaque`) inside the JavaScript that embeds your video player. See the links in my answer.

Comment: @SsRide360 I guess you're using javascript to embed it ... if you tell me which is the library that you use I can be more specific :)

Comment: In the edit I will show the flowplayer I use and how I make it (through js)

Comment: I tried this `$f('#rightVideoContent', {src: 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf', wmode: 'transparent'}` but I keep getting errors : `missing ) after argument list`

Comment: I also tried this: `clip: {
            wmode: 'transparent',
            url: videoLocation,
            autoPlay: true,
            autoBuffering: true
        },` Which did not give an error, but the clip was still above the `dialog`

Comment: Got it. Needed a ',' after `{src: 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf', wmode: 'transparent'},`

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to embed the flash with `wmode="transparent"`.

As in @locrizak's answer, you can also use `wmode="opaque"`, which is better because it's less processor intensive.

These should help:

- http://flowplayer.org/forum/2/10645
- http://flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/player.html#embedding

Answer (score 1):

You need a

```
wmode: "transparent/opaque"
```

parameter on the flash object.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this and Flowplayer wouldn't add the wmode parameter no matter what i tried

I used this jQuery snippet and it solved it!

```
$('#videocontainerid object').prepend('<param name="wmode" value="opaque">');
```

or for every object:

```
$('object').prepend('<param name="wmode" value="opaque">');
```

Answer (score 1):

see [HTML Overlays in Flowplayer](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/wmode.html)
example code:

```
flowplayer("player", {  
    src:"http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf",  
    wmode: "opaque" // This allows the HTML to hide the flash content  
    }, {  
    clip: {  
      url: 'http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv'  
    }  
});
```