# z-index and flash components

Tags: flash, z-index

I usually can get z-index to work properly, but on this page, and this flash file, i am unable to...

page is located: https://www.bcidaho.com/waiveship/index.asp

I have tried wrapping the flash file in a div and setting the z-index:-1; and other variations...but my drop down navigation keeps falling behind the flash file...

I have been using FireBug and modifying everything under the sun with my navigation menu, but to no avail. any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the drop down menu on the main navigation falls behind the flash file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the **wmode** from **window** to **transparent** for your swf file. This should fix it.

More info about **wmode** you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embed)

Comment: blam... worked perfect, and i set the z-index:1;... thank you.