# Expandable banner CSS,Javascript,Flash

Tags: javascript, css, flash, position, ads

I have to create a banner that expands over content when moused over and then contracts on mouse out. I have managed to create the expand/contract animations and actions but I am having trouble positioning the  that the flash file is in to ensure that it's flows over other elements on the page.

Can anyone give me a lesson on doing this. I imagine its a bit of CSS and a little bit of javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at wmode=transparent for getting flash files to work nicely with other elements on the page.

If you can add the wmode to the flash object, you shouldn't have any problems.

Just wrap the flash file in a div wrapper and position the div or do whatever you need that way.

[differences between using wmode="transparent", "opaque", or "window" for an embedded object on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embed)

Meant to add, if you change the wmode, and wrap it in a div, then you can assign the div a position of absolute and use z-index:99999 to have it above all other elements.