# jQuery: setting wmode to Youtube video for z-index handling

Tags: jquery, css, youtube, position, wmode

I'm doing this:

```
//z-index of flash objects
$('object').prepend('<param name="wmode" value="opaque">');
$('object embed').attr('wmode', 'opaque');
```

So, when I inspect the youtube video on my page it says:

```
<object width="500" height="281">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/KUi32-suXjY?version=3&amp;feature=oembed">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/KUi32-suXjY?version=3&amp;feature=oembed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500" height="281" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque"></object>
```

I have draggable objects with `fixed position` and `z-index:9999` on my page. However I have no change to make the youtube video stay behind this objects. The youtube video is always on top, even if I set the wmode.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe that Flash always appears on top of the other DOM elements, even if you tell it not to be.

Comment: no, it is working. I know it. I made it already working once. However that time with direct html code and not with injected html via javascript. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: What browser are you using? because in Safari and Firefox I can see the video behind the draggable elements.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i'm using chrome. Doesn't work in chrome, but seems to work in all other browsers, so screw it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Or you can use the new youtube method to embed videos It'd be like:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="481" height="295" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HgLviEa0YHo?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
```

and there it goes with the `wmode` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, however that's not working for me, cause Wordpress is still using the old embed code. See my link above, maybe you can see what i'm doing wrong here or what i'm missing.

Comment: Well I can see the player behind the draggable elements -> http://twitpic.com/7ae46g

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wmode **transparent**?

That's what I've used. Not sure what the difference between opaque and transparent is in this context.
[Using Window Mode (wmode) values](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_)

Also not sure, but maybe this will help:
[difference between opaque and transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embe)

Comment: thank you, but doesn't solve the problem … wheter transperent nor opaque seems to work. Don't get why. I posted the link to my question  above … maybe you can find out why the youtube video doesn't want to stay behind the black bars.