# Rounded Corners not displaying over top of flash

Tags: flash, css, rounded-corners

I have a bookmarklet that has rounded corners.

When using the bookmarklet over the top of a flash website and even a pdf document (I think) etc. Rounded corners appear as transparent squares.

[image]

Anyone come accross this and know how to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a question about programming? http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Yes, can it be resolved within the CSS?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by changing the wmode of the flash movie to transparent. This does reduce the performance of your flash, but it works, see this [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embe) for more info on the performance hit.