# Chrome You Tube embed display errors with liteAccordion

Tags: jquery, html, flash, google-chrome, embed

In my project at the moment I am using Nicola Hibbert's [liteAccordion slider](http://nicolahibbert.com/liteaccordion-v2/).

I have it all set up and it's working nicely but the project needs to have a YouTube video on each of the slides.

I have used the classic embed code from YouTube to get the desired result, In Firefox and other browsers it's all good, singing and dancing.

In Chrome, tears stream down my face as it has totally broke.

I tried to use the new iframe from YouTube instead but get the same problem and I don't have a clue how to fix it. I have created a lower end version which is able to view on my website, I would be so grateful if the great minds on here could help me out :0)

You can view it 
[here](http://jonleesmith.co.uk).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding &wmode=opaque to your link, it worked for me!

Comment: <iframe width="250" height="199" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KL68jbmGo-0?rel=0&wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>

Comment: So odd that there is such a difference between transparent & opaque. Is this a Chrome bug? Some vaguely enlightening documentation in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embe

Comment: Thanks Annika! Worked perfectly