# Flashplayer overflowing outside container

Tags: css, flash

Here is the web page I'm working on: http://sebastianbiermanlytle.com/games.htm. The flashplayer is at the bottom. It's overflowing in both directions and sometimes covers the main menu. I tried using overflow:hidden on the container, but nothing happened. How do I hide the overflow?

Comment: what is the wmode of the flash? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embe

Comment: I hadn't set it, but I just tried all three options - nothing happened with any of them

Comment: Inspector says `.entry { overlow: hidden }` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position:absolute` and `left:-25.5px` from css style of `object` with id `rpgEngine`  and it will be OK.

Comment: The problem is I need those attributes to keep the game in the middle of the screen

Comment: If you're really worried about centering, you could always use `margins`. After all absolute positioning won't center it correctly for different screen resolutions.

Comment: Didn't think about margins - that got me what I wanted