# Flash player in an iframe showing above the navigation div

Tags: css, flash, iframe, z-index

In my site i've used an iframe with flash content(not a you tube video)

```
 <iframe id="flvIframe" width="934" height="750" frameborder="0" src="XXXflashplayer" style="z-index: 1;"></iframe>
```

i have navigation bar in my site when we hover on a single nav element we'll display a
    `div#NavInfo` with some options with an .Below the navigation bar i had a div where i display an iframe with flash content.

I want to place the nav elements div#NavInfo above an iframe`#flvIframe`(with flash content).

I have used z-index position: absolute ,position relative ....etc.
    `z-index:-1` to flash and give `z-index:100` to div

```
position: absolute;
top: ...px;
left: ...px;
```

it works fine only in google chrome but not working in all other browsers

I have searched a lot but couldn't get fixed please advise..

Comment: Do you have an access to the "XXXflashplayer" page?

Comment: yes i can access "XXXflashplayer" page

Comment: and you can change a flash object code in its html? if so add `wmode="transparent"` parameter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embe

Comment: Hay i've fixed this problem is with my iframe url :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this - http://slightlymore.co.uk/examples/flash-z-index/

Please note that your flash swf should have parameter wmode="opaque". also you can play with z-index of div i.e. div#NavInfo for higher priority