# Any HTML content overlapping video player on iphone not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

Will try to explain my question with an example:

Home page has a large flowplayer (video) after the header. And the login tab uses bootstrap models which appears on top of the video player onclick with a normal login form.

Everything works fine on all browsers and devices except iphone or ipad.

By doing some google search I have come to a conclusion that apple does not support any html overlapping the video content.

Could not find any discussions on this topic on this site too, so posting this question here hoping that someone can provide an alternative or a way to get this working (overlapping models on video player).

Comment: dam i had this same issue but i did solved it don't remember how :( but i am sure it can be solved.

Comment: I hope there is a way around it. apple video player has been a pain, but sadly can't ignore them too. @ImranBughio

Comment: did you tried the answer i gave?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
wmode="opaque"
```

to the

```
<object>
```

OR

```
<embed>
```

tag parameters and see if it helps.

Comment: <object> parameter has already been set to opaque, but still it does not work. 

I did refer to this documentation ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embe)), which I thought might solve the issue with iphones. But sadly does not work for iphones.

Comment: can you share a link or something?