# jQuery datepicker hidden behind Flash banner

Tags: jquery, html, flash

I have a textbox on asp.net webform, which shows the jQuery datepicker on click. There is also a flash banner on my page.

My problem is that the datepicker is appears hidden behind the flash banner, and I need it to appear on top of the banner.

Comment: Next time on.. give a sensible title to your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I place HTML content above a Flash movie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123529/how-do-i-place-html-content-above-a-flash-movie)

Answer (score 2):

Flash will be always above all content. THis is how browsers work

Also checkout this [How do I place HTML content above a Flash movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123529/how-do-i-place-html-content-above-a-flash-movie)

Comment: Won't this prevent flash always being on top? http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html

Comment: Yes. Solution in rlb.usa's answer + my comment.

Comment: `The WMODE parameter is supported only on some browser/Flash Player version combinations. If the WMODE parameter is not supported, the Flash movie will always display on top. `

Answer (score 2):

Use the `z-index` property on your elements and set it so that the datepicker has the bigger index. http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: This, and make sure to set the `wmode` attribute for your object and embed elements to either `opaque` or `transparent`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you set the wmode value to "transparent" in the code that embeds the flash movie.

You need to add/edit the following:

**<param name="wmode" value="transparent">**
and 
**wmode="transparent"** inside the <embed src=”....”> tag.